# Is the following relation between $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ true?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ bounded.

If $\mu(A) > 0$, $0 <s < \alpha$ and $\forall x \in A$, is it true that 
$$ \liminf_{r \to 0}\frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{r^\alpha} \geq 1 \implies \limsup_{r \to 0}\frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{r^s} \leq 1?$$

Why yes/not?

I can't clarify whether it is true or not.
Can someone please help me?

Thank you!